# How to get original word level entity instead of wordpiece tokens in BERT NER

Tags: python, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, labeling

I have a trained BERT model that I am willing to use to annotate some text.

I am using the transformers pipeline for the NER task in the following way:

```
mode = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(<my_model_path>)
tokenize = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(<my_model_path>)

nlp_ner = pipeline(
    "ner",
    model=mode,
    tokenizer=tokenize
)
```

Then, I am obtaining the prediction results by calling:

```
text = "3) Rewrite the last sentence “scanning probe ... perovskite family”. The current one is quite confusing."
result = nlp_ner(text)
```

Where the returned result is:

```
[{'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99999774, 'index': 1, 'word': '3', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999979, 'index': 2, 'word': ')', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_8', 'score': 0.9999897, 'index': 3, 'word': 'rewrite', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999976, 'index': 4, 'word': 'the', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999962, 'index': 5, 'word': 'last', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999975, 'index': 6, 'word': 'sentence', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.99998623, 'index': 7, 'word': '“', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.99997735, 'index': 8, 'word': 'scanning', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.9941041, 'index': 9, 'word': 'probe', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.999994, 'index': 10, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99999696, 'index': 11, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999976, 'index': 12, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.99998647, 'index': 13, 'word': 'per', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.9999939, 'index': 14, 'word': '##ovsk', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.99999154, 'index': 15, 'word': '##ite', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.9999942, 'index': 16, 'word': 'family', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.9997022, 'index': 17, 'word': '”', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999929, 'index': 18, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999977, 'index': 19, 'word': 'the', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99999076, 'index': 20, 'word': 'current', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99996257, 'index': 21, 'word': 'one', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_8', 'score': 0.9169066, 'index': 22, 'word': 'is', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.6795164, 'index': 23, 'word': 'quite', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.7315716, 'index': 24, 'word': 'conf', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_9', 'score': 0.9067044, 'index': 25, 'word': '##using', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999925, 'index': 26, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}]
```

The problem I am facing now is that I would like to annotate the predicted classes back to the text itself, but this looks complicated as the prediction results are not indexing words by expolding them with a space, but for example, composed words are seen as multiple words, etc.

Is there a way to annotate back the text (for example, in Doccanno JSON format) that is not too complex?

My goal is to be able to say: For all the "LABEL_9", highlight the initial text with a specific html class. Or even easier, find the start and the end index for all words predicted as being of class "LABEL_9".

Answer (score 2):

The Tokenizer you are using inside the pipeline does not give out the offset information and so you get None in the model response for `start`. Change it to Fast Tokenizer and you should get the `start` location.

#### Solution

```
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForTokenClassification, PreTrainedTokenizerFast

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

nlp_ner = pipeline(
    "ner",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)

text = "3) Rewrite the last sentence “scanning probe ... perovskite family”. The current one is quite confusing."
results = nlp_ner(text)

for result in results:
  start = result["start"]
  end = result["start"]+len(result["word"].replace("##", ""))
  tag = result["entity"]

  print (f"Entity: {tag}, Start:{start}, End:{end}, Token:{text[start:end]}")
```

Output:

```
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:0, End:1, Token:3
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:1, End:2, Token:)
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:3, End:5, Token:Re
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:5, End:10, Token:write
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:11, End:14, Token:the
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:15, End:19, Token:last
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:20, End:28, Token:sentence
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:29, End:30, Token:“
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:30, End:38, Token:scanning
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:39, End:44, Token:probe
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:45, End:46, Token:.
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:46, End:47, Token:.
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:47, End:48, Token:.
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:49, End:52, Token:per
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:52, End:54, Token:ov
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:54, End:57, Token:ski
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:57, End:59, Token:te
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:60, End:66, Token:family
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:66, End:67, Token:”
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:67, End:68, Token:.
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:69, End:72, Token:The
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:73, End:80, Token:current
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:81, End:84, Token:one
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:85, End:87, Token:is
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:88, End:93, Token:quite
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:94, End:103, Token:confusing
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:103, End:104, Token:.
```

#### wordpiece tokenizer

BERT tokenizer is a wordpiece tokenizer, i.e, a single word might get tokenzied into multiple tokens (for example `perovskite` in the above). It is a standard practice to use the entity of the first token in case if a word gets tokenized into multiple. You can use other strategies like max voting etc. Below is the logic to use to get the entities per words.

```
formatted_results = []
for result in results:
  end = result["start"]+len(result["word"].replace("##", ""))  
  
  if result["word"].startswith("##"):
    formatted_results[-1]["end"] = end
    formatted_results[-1]["word"]+= result["word"].replace("##", "")
  else:
    formatted_results.append({
        'start': result["start"], 
        'end': end,
        'entity': result["entity"],
        'index': result["index"],
        'score': result["score"],
        'word': result["word"]})

for result in formatted_results:
    print (f"""Entity: {result["entity"]}, Start:{result["start"]}, End:{result["end"]}, word:{text[result["start"]:result["end"]]}""")
```

Output:

```
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:0, End:1, word:3
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:1, End:2, word:)
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:3, End:10, word:Rewrite
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:11, End:14, word:the
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:15, End:19, word:last
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:20, End:28, word:sentence
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:29, End:30, word:“
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:30, End:38, word:scanning
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:39, End:44, word:probe
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:45, End:46, word:.
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:46, End:47, word:.
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:47, End:48, word:.
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:49, End:59, word:perovskite
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:60, End:66, word:family
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:66, End:67, word:”
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:67, End:68, word:.
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:69, End:72, word:The
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:73, End:80, word:current
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:81, End:84, word:one
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:85, End:87, word:is
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:88, End:93, word:quite
Entity: LABEL_1, Start:94, End:103, word:confusing
Entity: LABEL_0, Start:103, End:104, word:.
```

Comment: Thank you mujjigam, I will test your solution during the day and come back to you asap.

Answer (score 1):

The only subtle point for keeping in mind here is that the transformers tokenizer doesn't split sentences using white spaces, they break texts into subwords (in most cases!). Two consecutive `#`s always signify the start of a subword, this property can be exploited for reconstructing original words.

With this in mind an unprincipled implementation for converting the output of the pipeline into Doccano format would be like this:

**UPDATE**: adding a new argument to the function `original_text` would help with reconstructing text and getting rid of the extra spaces.

```
text = "3) Rewrite the last sentence “scanning probe ... perovskite family”. The current one is quite confusing."
output = [{'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99999774, 'index': 1, 'word': '3', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999979, 'index': 2, 'word': ')', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_8', 'score': 0.9999897, 'index': 3, 'word': 'rewrite', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999976, 'index': 4, 'word': 'the', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999962, 'index': 5, 'word': 'last', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999975, 'index': 6, 'word': 'sentence', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.99998623, 'index': 7, 'word': '“', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.99997735, 'index': 8, 'word': 'scanning', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.9941041, 'index': 9, 'word': 'probe', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.999994, 'index': 10, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99999696, 'index': 11, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999976, 'index': 12, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.99998647, 'index': 13, 'word': 'per', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.9999939, 'index': 14, 'word': '##ovsk', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.99999154, 'index': 15, 'word': '##ite', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_3', 'score': 0.9999942, 'index': 16, 'word': 'family', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.9997022, 'index': 17, 'word': '”', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999929, 'index': 18, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999977, 'index': 19, 'word': 'the', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99999076, 'index': 20, 'word': 'current', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.99996257, 'index': 21, 'word': 'one', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_8', 'score': 0.9169066, 'index': 22, 'word': 'is', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.6795164, 'index': 23, 'word': 'quite', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.7315716, 'index': 24, 'word': 'conf', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_9', 'score': 0.9067044, 'index': 25, 'word': '##using', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.9999925, 'index': 26, 'word': '.', 'start': None, 'end': None}]
def pipelineoutput_2_doccon(pipelineoutput, original_text, merge_labels=True):
  words = [item['word'] for item in pipelineoutput]
  labels = [item['entity'] for item in pipelineoutput]
  tags = []
  text = ''
  for idx, (w, l) in enumerate(zip(words, labels)):    
    if w.startswith('##'):
      length=len(text)
      text+=w[2:]
      tags.append([length, length+len(w[2:]), l, w])
    else:
      if text!='':
        text+=' '
      length=len(text)
      text+=w
      tags.append([length, length+len(w), l, w])
      length+=len(text)
  if not merge_labels:
    final_tags = []
    temp_text = original_text.lower()
    accumulated = 0
    for item in tags:
      
      start = temp_text.find(item[-1])
      end = start+len(item[-1])
      final_tags.append([accumulated+start, accumulated+end, item[-2]])
      temp_text = temp_text[end:]
      
      accumulated+=end
    return {"text": original_text, "label":final_tags}
  else:
    merged_tags = []
    for idx in range(len(tags)):
      if (tags[idx][1]==len(text) or text[tags[idx][1]]==' '):
        merged_tags.append(tags[idx])
      else:
        tags[idx+1][0] = tags[idx][0]
        tags[idx+1][-1] = tags[idx][-1]+tags[idx+1][-1].replace('##', '')
    final_tags = []
    temp_text = original_text.lower()
    accumulated = 0
    for item in merged_tags:
      
      start = temp_text.find(item[-1])
      end = start+len(item[-1])
      final_tags.append([accumulated+start, accumulated+end, item[-2]])
      temp_text = temp_text[end:]
      
      accumulated+=end
      
    return {"text": original_text, "label":final_tags}
pipelineoutput_2_doccon(output, text, merge_labels=False)
```

output:

```
{'label': [[0, 1, 'LABEL_1'],
  [1, 2, 'LABEL_1'],
  [3, 10, 'LABEL_8'],
  [11, 14, 'LABEL_1'],
  [15, 19, 'LABEL_1'],
  [20, 28, 'LABEL_1'],
  [29, 30, 'LABEL_2'],
  [30, 38, 'LABEL_2'],
  [39, 44, 'LABEL_3'],
  [45, 46, 'LABEL_1'],
  [46, 47, 'LABEL_1'],
  [47, 48, 'LABEL_1'],
  [49, 59, 'LABEL_3'],
  [60, 66, 'LABEL_3'],
  [66, 67, 'LABEL_2'],
  [67, 68, 'LABEL_1'],
  [69, 72, 'LABEL_1'],
  [73, 80, 'LABEL_1'],
  [81, 84, 'LABEL_1'],
  [85, 87, 'LABEL_8'],
  [88, 93, 'LABEL_1'],
  [94, 103, 'LABEL_9'],
  [103, 104, 'LABEL_1']],
 'text': '3) Rewrite the last sentence “scanning probe ... perovskite family”. The current one is quite confusing.'}
```

As you may be noticed label assignment is happening at the subword level. If the sequence labeler has gained good knowledge about the task it's expected to assign unique labels to subwords of a word otherwise it's your choice to aggregate labels in the way which meets your goals the best.

Comment: Thamks a lot Meti. Quick question, any idea on how to get read of the extra spaces added by recombining the sentance? For example, the initial "3)" was changed to "3 )", etc.

Comment: I have updated the function and I hope it helps @MilosCuculovic

Comment: Thank sou Meti. And another question, it seems the merge_labels flag is returning the same result when set to True or False. Can the merge_labels flag be used to merge the labels in the way that if 3 words are labelled within the same label, those get merged all together as a single label on all 3 words? Was this the initial purpose of merge_labels?

Comment: As I mentioned the tokenizer of the `huggingface` breaks sentences into `subwords` so you get a label for each subword, `merge_labels` flag would reconstruct the whole word by combining subwords and assigning the last label to the entire group.